# Ubuntu upgrade to 12.10 in system which have RAID 5

Tags: upgrade

My system has one HDD (where Ubuntu is) and 4 1½ TB SATA drives in software RAID 5 configuration.

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10. In the upgrade process it said some thing about RAID. Now when I boot the system Ubuntu will not successfuly start.

I think it tries boot from the RAID array. Is there anything to fix this problem.

Comment: Little bit more information. My system is amd64. I found out that if I use i386 10.04 boot dvd in drive at boot it will boot to ubuntu 12.10. Ihaven't tried anything other distribution but I think that it will work too. Is there solution for this problem. I wuoldn't like to boot this way.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04LTS had RAID built in I discovered this when I installed the *disks* application and on opening the *disks* application I noticed a menu item which would have make it possible to setup RAID but I didn't have the extra Hard drives to hand therefore did not try this.

I am running a personal computer based on the ASUS m2n68-la (Narra3) which has two RAID controllers built in but they can also operate as normal hard drive/CDRW/DVDRW controllers although Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't seem to have this as I have checked the *disks* application on Ubuntu 12.10 and the RAID option doesn't show up.

I hope that this helps so **if you want RAID then your distro should be Ubuntu 12.04LTS** if you don't want RAID then Ubuntu 12.10 will do just fine.